# Error while using 'author' option in 'todonotes' package

Tags: key-value, todonotes

I am trying to use the `author` option in the `\todo` command provided by `todonotes` package. This is clearly mentioned in its manual. Following is the code snippet and the error it produces:

Snippet:

```
\usepackage{todonotes}
\todo[author=Doe]{This is a comment.}
```

Error:

```
! Package xkeyval Error: `author' undefined in families `todonotes'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
```

Comment: No problem here when using a [MWE](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mOPS5.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have to update package `todonotes`, from its source `todonotes.dtx`:

```
% \changes{0.9.9}{2011/10/22}{Added author option, implementation provided by 
%             Xavier Alameda-Pineda. [...]
```

Comment: If this is the case, then a [distribution update](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764) would make this a duplicate.

Comment: You are right. Installed version of todonotes is old (2011/04/21). However, I don't have the super user privileges to upgrade this package. Is there a virtual environment builder for latex like [`virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) for python or `cabal` (?) for haskell?

Comment: @shoban: If you are using TeX Live, then you can put the updated file in the `TEXMFHOME` tree, usually: `~/texmf/tex/latex/todonotes/todonotes.sty`.